# Burning sketch with I2C

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, atmega328

Not a pure Arduino question really. I'm actually using a standalone ATmega168. So far I've been using AVR-ISP programmer (working from AVR Studio) to program the chip. After everything is done, the chip will be covered and I will only have access to the I2C pins. The MISO,MOSI, etc pins will be unreachable.

I was just wondering if there was a way to use the I2C pins to update the program that is burned on the chip. I won't need to burn the bootloader again, but just to update the program if it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a I2C bootloader to the AVR. There seems to be a [project that has already created such a bootloader](https://code.google.com/p/raspy-juice/wiki/Bootloader).

Atmel has provided a [TWI/I2C bootloader](http://www.atmel.com/ru/ru/Images/doc8435.pdf) for their XMega processors (not the ATmega168).

Next problem is uploading the code via I2C. You'd need some hardware to convert USB  to I2C. And some software to talk to this hardware. The last part is probably supported by AVR studio, as Atmel has provided an I2C bootloader. Though I'm not sure both of the above bootloaders are using a compatible protocol over the I2C.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [miniboot](https://github.com/mihaigalos/miniboot). I implemented it as a self-contained bootloader. Instructions about uploading from USB to I2C are also provided. Live long and prosper.

Comment: Elaborate the point. Link only answers die of link rot.